How do I rotate the screen of an android device by a certain number of degrees?
I wear a smartwatch (Galaxy Watch 4) with the screen facing my wrist, and for greater convenience, I would like to rotate the screen not 90 degrees, but approximately 40-45 degrees. Unfortunately, I found information only about rotation at 90/180/270 and 360 degrees, which is 0 degrees. Maybe there is a way to rotate the screen by an arbitrary number of degrees?1 photo shows how I was able to do it (90 degrees).2 photo shows how I would like to do it (approximately 45 degrees).
enter image description here
enter image description here
adb shell settings put system user_rotation 1 I tried this command, but it rotates the screen 90 degrees, and I need 45.

Pixels are in general rectangular, therefore without a computation and difficult math only 0, 90, 180, 270 degrees are possible.

You cannot rotate it 45 degrees, this is not possible.
But alternativly you could design your app to be tilted by 45 degrees. And make settings turn this on or off.
